# Powershell - Build strings from a list

Tags: powershell

I have an object that holds numbers $names

```
name
123
456
789
012
...
```

I need to compose a title for an item in TFS like:
My Title 123 456 789 012 ...

Add-VSTeamWorkItem -Title "My title $names" -Description "This is a description" -WorkItemType Task

If it will be run in a loop many work items will be created
What is the right way to do it?

I managed to build the title. Now I need to build the description that contains in each line a title that I get from the TFS. I tried this but its not working because the object holds only one title

```
foreach ($patch in $patches)
{
    $title = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patch.Patch).fields.'system.Title'
}
```

Comment: Is `"My title $names"` not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data suggests that `$names` contains an array of objects *with a `.name` property*, and that you want to space-concatenate these property values inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```
"My Title $($names.name)"
```

If, by contrast, the inclusion of column header `name` in your sample data is just a formatting artifact, the solution is simpler:

```
"My Title $names"
```

When PowerShell stringifies an array, it space-concatenates its stringified elements, so that `"$(1, 2)"` becomes verbatim `1 2`, for instance.